# Strange result when running query over a table created from a result of another query

Tags: google-bigquery

Since yesterday, 1-09-2012, I can't run any queries over a table that has been created from the result of another query.

example query:

```
SELECT region FROM [project.table] LIMIT 1000
```

result:

```
Query Failed
Error: Field 'region' is incompatible with the table schema.
49077933619
```

These kinds of queries passed successfully every day, last couple of weeks. Has anybody else encountered a similar problem?

Comment: if you change region to \`region\` what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added some additional schema checking on friday. I was unable to reproduce the problem but I'll look into your examples (I was able to find your failed job in the logs). I'm in the process of turning off the additional schema checking in the meantime. Please try again and let us know if the problem continues.

Comment: I am using executing the queries through GAE (big query java api) then I create a new table form the result, that is a daily process. Then via different queries are executed and reports are created.